# How to calculate output impedance in this circuit?

Tags: amplifier

0.3k where did come from?? How to calculate output impedance in this circuit I don't understand this
[image]

Comment: It’s a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

There is negative feedback around that middle stage via the 10k resistor between collector and base that will lower its output resistance.

Comment: Yes - and, therefore, the form of the red arrow (Zout) in the above diagram is misleading. This arrow should point to the current source as well.